# How to configure proxy settings on Linux XFCE?

Tags: browser, proxy, xfce

I have been running into problems whilst configuring my XFCE proxy settings. Whilst declaring the proxy variables in /etc/environment seems to work for wget, curl and chrome, it has no effect on apt or firefox. In addition, there seems to be a need for duplicated proxy variables, one in lower case, the other in higher case.

Can anyone list the full set of configuration changes needed to effectively inform all applications to use proxy settings across the XFCE environment and perhaps comment on the need for upper and lower case settings?, Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The environment variables for controlling proxy behaviour are as follows: http_proxy, ftp_proxy, https_proxy, all_proxy and no_proxy. Unfortunately, some applications require these in upper case, other applications need these variables in lower case, that just the way it is.

The format for declaring a proxy exclusion list is simply a comma separated list, the declaration has some wildcard capabilities but not all applications respect these:

```
no_proxy=127.0.0.1,*.local.com
```

Your /etc/environment needs to have the following proxy configuration:

```
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local
all_proxy=socks://proxy.example.com:8080/
ALL_PROXY=socks://proxy.example.com:8080/
http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:8080
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:8080
FTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:8080  
https_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:8080
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

You must log out before your desktop environment will refresh it's environment variables. As all desktop applications are started by the desktop environment, they subsequently inherit its environment settings.

Next, you'll need to update your apt configuration. Create a file called /etc/apt/apt.conf and edit it to contain these declarations:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy.example.com:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://proxy.example.com:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://proxy.example.com:8080/";
```

Verify that apt has picked up these settings via this command

```
apt-config dump  | grep -i proxy # lists the proxy settings
```

[Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxProxyConfig) will respect the proxy environment variables but Firefox does not, even though it has apparently addressed this [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66057)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio

Comment: Firefox now has an option under Preferences --> Advanced --> (Network tab) --> Settings (under "Connection" section) to "Use system proxy settings," which will apparently use the system settings from the environment file.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the "dconf-tools" Gnome package in Xfce and it works.

Comment: Save my day! Midori browser seems to read the proxy value set in dconf-tools...

Comment: did not work with XFCE 4.12 Xubuntu 16 LTS and FF 78.0.2 (64bit) and after re-login env vars were not set either.

Comment: Worked on Debian 10 with XFCE 4.12! Package was named dconf-editor, proxy settings were under /system/proxy. They worked when i set "Use system proxy settings" in FF.

Comment: Does Xfce need to be the session manager for it to work or not?

Answer (score 4):

**Using XFCE 4.10 on ArchLinux**

I've tried *dconf* too, but it didn't work for me.

**Using Linux Mint 13 XCFE**

I was able to configure the proxy using 'gnone-control-center network'

```
apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

don't forget to reset xfce as your session manager after installing gnome-control-center package:

```
update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```